# Dynamic field generation on database and generate dynamic fields for a form

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

Recently I saw a website application and there was an interesting HTML form that took my attention! in the website manager system you can define a form like employment form and you can define which field or fields do you need in your form.

For example you can want a form with Birthday,Name, Lastname and Gender fields that Birthday and Name and Lastname types are `Textbox` and Gender type is a `Checkbox` so you can generate you optimized form and another one can create her/his optimized form too.

After that any one can fill your form in the website clients page and you can see all filled forms in the manager site. so there is a big question for me, how does the website database designed that it can change the fields dynamically?! in the first view I thought there is a column in the database that it's type is XML and it can generate any form base on XML in single column. but I think it's not a good way because we will have hug database by many similar data (XML text are mostly similar), so is there a better way to do this?

**note**: the database was on sqlserver2012 and I asked the website manager that how did you do it, he told me this type of design is called 'property engine' for I searched for it but I don't find any useful information! so what is your Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think that you necessarily need XML to implement such a system, it is question of choice. It could be implemented for example like this:

[image]

It means: just take one step forward in the direction META in your database model.

But of course you have to implement the application around such a database model which is not simple. Surely there already exist many implementations of this.

---

You can check also this [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/204097/dynamic-form-builder-forms-and-database-design) - the design here is a little simpler not allowing reuse of Fields within various Forms - this could be ok and even better, depends on what you plan to implement. So you would have relation 1:N between Form and Field tables.

[image]

So your database fields would be like this:

```
Form
-----
  FormID (PK)
  FormName
  UserId (FK to users)
 (other fields)

FormField
-------------
  FormFieldId (PK)
  FormID (FK to form)
  FieldTypeId (FK to FieldType)
  FieldName  (or Caption ...)
  (other fields)

FieldType
-------------
  id (PK)
  name

FilledForm
-------------------
  FilledFormId (PK)
   +IPAddress, data about who filled the form...


FilledFormField
-------------------
  FilledFormFieldId (PK)
  FilledFormId (FK)
  FormFieldId (FK)
  Value
```

If you do not need to track info about who filled the form, you can also remove FilledForm table from the model.

In such a database design do not forget to create proper primary keys and indexes.

Comment: thank you VDohnal so much, I have some ideas to implement this database, but I'm searching for new and better solution, your answer is a new and good solution for me, but can you show me some tutorials or tell me some keywords to help me find more examples?